# Current timeline for hiring a tenure-track position amid the pandemic

Tags: united-states, job-search, tenure-track, covid-19

Even though there are already a lot of posts concerning the timeline for hiring a tenure track position in the US, I am curious to know the current timeline amid the COVID-19 pandemic starting 2020.

Currently (in March), I have seen many top-tier/teaching institutions finalizing the positions for which they started the first-round interview in December 2020. However, there are still a few smaller universities that have just started the hiring process in February 2021, although their posting was in November 2020. In particular, I have had a first-round interview so far and was asked to wait for 4 weeks for the next decision. As far as I know, top candidates are normally contacted within 1-2 weeks from the first interview. Therefore, I am supposing that I am not their top choice if the current timeline is the same as before.

Anyone please share your experience.

Comment: Not US-based, but from a European perspective, I can say that hiring timelines are currently less predictable than they used to be. It all hinges on the people involved in the decision-making, who, due to corona-related issues, might push things back a fair bit.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Thanks for your comment. Was in Europe so I can understand that the tough hiring process becomes tougher in this pandemic. Plus, normally in the US, the job market opens around September each year, but in Europe, it is hard to predict when they start the search.

Answer (score 3):

> I am curious to know the current timeline amid the COVID-19 pandemic starting 2020.

There is not one.  It is utter chaos because nobody knows how much money they will have next fall.

Comment: I am still curious. This is now March and they could not figure out how much money they will have next fall? No deadline information from the upper division?